# Spring Gateway duplicate headers causing io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: HTTP header is larger than

Tags: spring-boot, axios, nuxt.js, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using nuxt.js with Spring Gateway and I'm experiencing a strange issue where it appears multiple request to the gateway end up duplicating the headers containing auth tokens causing the HTTP header to exceed the limit.

To get around cors issues, my frontend sites behind the gateway and all request are made to the gateway through 8080 and forwarded to my frontend / backend end points.

My setup

**Spring Gateway**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: auth-service
          uri: ${domain.gateway.proxyurls.auth}
          predicates:
            - Path=/portal/auth/**
        - id: business-object-service
          uri: ${domain.gateway.proxyurls.businessobject}
          predicates:
            - Path=/portal/api/business-object/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/portal(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}       
        ######################################################
        ##                                                  ##
        ##   The default goes to the nuxt frontend app      ##
        ##                                                  ##
        ######################################################

        - id: frontend
          uri: ${domain.gateway.proxyurls.frontend}
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
```

**Nuxt.js frontend with request**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-if="$auth.$state.loggedIn">
      Username {{$auth.user.username}}
      <br /> <br />
      <button @click="$auth.logout()">Logout</button>
      <br />
      <ol>
        <li>{{newsItem1}}</li>
        <li>{{newsItem2}}</li>
        <li>{{newsItem3}}</li>
        <li>{{newsItem4}}</li>
        <li>{{newsItem5}}</li>
      </ol>

      Fetch <button @click="$fetch">Refresh</button>

      <p>

      </p>
    </template>
    <a
      v-else
      href="#"
      @click="$auth.loginWith('hri')"
    >Login</a>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "Home",

  data () {
    return {
      newsItem1: '',
      newsItem2: '',
      newsItem3: '',
      newsItem4: '',
      newsItem4: ''
    }
  },

  fetchOnServer: true,

  async fetch () {
    this.newsItem1 = await this.$axios.$get('/portal/api/business-object/reports/status-info-rpci')
    this.newsItem2 = await this.$axios.$get('/portal/api/business-object/reports/status-info-alb')
    this.newsItem3 = await this.$axios.$get('/portal/api/business-object/reports/status-info-alb')
    this.newsItem4 = await this.$axios.$get('/portal/api/business-object/reports/status-info-alb')
    this.newsItem4 = await this.$axios.$get('/portal/api/business-object/reports/status-info-alb')

  }

}
</script>
```

trace:

```
2020-05-28 05:32:15.513 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-6]
o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: frontend
2020-05-28 05:32:15.514 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-6]
o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET
http://localhost:8080/portal/] to Route{id='frontend',
uri=http://localhost:3000, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/**], match
trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[DedupeResponseHeader
Authorization Cookie = RETAIN_UNIQUE], order = 1]], metadata={}}
2020-05-28 05:32:15.514 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-6]
o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : [d15d386e-19] Mapped to
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@343c0132
2020-05-28 05:32:15.514 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-6]
o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted
gatewayFilterFactories:
[[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@59918c8f},
order = -2147483648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@4bc9ca97},
order = -2147482648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@2450256f},
order = -1],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@24197b13}, order = 0],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@2776fd8f},
order = 0], [[DedupeResponseHeader Authorization Cookie =
RETAIN_UNIQUE], order = 1],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@2b7facc7},
order = 10000],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayNoLoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$NoLoadBalancerClientFilter@1c62c3fd},
order = 10100],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@71b97eeb},
order = 2147483646],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@2c60ce47},
order = 2147483647],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@1c74d19},
order = 2147483647]] 2020-05-28 05:32:15.532 DEBUG 8492 ---
[ctor-http-nio-7] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route
matched: auth-service 2020-05-28 05:32:15.532 DEBUG 8492 ---
[ctor-http-nio-7] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping
[Exchange: POST http://localhost:3000/portal/auth/oauth/token] to
Route{id='auth-service', uri=http://localhost:8900, order=0,
predicate=Paths: [/portal/auth/**], match trailing slash: true,
gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath /portal/auth(?<segment>/?.*) =
'${segment}'], order = 1]], metadata={}} 2020-05-28 05:32:15.532 DEBUG
8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-7] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   :
[b25a5952-20] Mapped to
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@343c0132
2020-05-28 05:32:15.533 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-7]
o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted
gatewayFilterFactories:
[[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@59918c8f},
order = -2147483648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@4bc9ca97},
order = -2147482648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@2450256f},
order = -1],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@24197b13}, order = 0],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@2776fd8f},
order = 0], [[RewritePath /portal/auth(?<segment>/?.*) =
'${segment}'], order = 1],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@2b7facc7},
order = 10000],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayNoLoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$NoLoadBalancerClientFilter@1c62c3fd},
order = 10100],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@71b97eeb},
order = 2147483646],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@2c60ce47},
order = 2147483647],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@1c74d19},
order = 2147483647]] 2020-05-28 05:32:15.549 DEBUG 8492 ---
[ctor-http-nio-8] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route
matched: auth-service 2020-05-28 05:32:15.549 DEBUG 8492 ---
[ctor-http-nio-8] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping
[Exchange: GET http://localhost:3000/portal/auth/api/users/me] to
Route{id='auth-service', uri=http://localhost:8900, order=0,
predicate=Paths: [/portal/auth/**], match trailing slash: true,
gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath /portal/auth(?<segment>/?.*) =
'${segment}'], order = 1]], metadata={}} 2020-05-28 05:32:15.549 DEBUG
8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-8] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   :
[83756017-21] Mapped to
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@343c0132
2020-05-28 05:32:15.549 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-8]
o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted
gatewayFilterFactories:
[[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@59918c8f},
order = -2147483648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@4bc9ca97},
order = -2147482648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@2450256f},
order = -1],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@24197b13}, order = 0],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@2776fd8f},
order = 0], [[RewritePath /portal/auth(?<segment>/?.*) =
'${segment}'], order = 1],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@2b7facc7},
order = 10000],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayNoLoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$NoLoadBalancerClientFilter@1c62c3fd},
order = 10100],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@71b97eeb},
order = 2147483646],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@2c60ce47},
order = 2147483647],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@1c74d19},
order = 2147483647]] 2020-05-28 05:32:15.566 DEBUG 8492 ---
[ctor-http-nio-9] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route
matched: business-object-service 2020-05-28 05:32:15.566 DEBUG 8492
--- [ctor-http-nio-9] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET
http://localhost:3000/portal/api/business-object/reports/status-info-rpci]
to Route{id='business-object-service', uri=http://localhost:9400,
order=0, predicate=Paths: [/portal/api/business-object/**], match
trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath
/portal(?<segment>/?.*) = '${segment}'], order = 1],
[[DedupeResponseHeader Authorization Cookie = RETAIN_UNIQUE], order =
2]], metadata={}} 2020-05-28 05:32:15.566 DEBUG 8492 ---
[ctor-http-nio-9] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   :
[f71d986f-22] Mapped to
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@343c0132
2020-05-28 05:32:15.567 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-9]
o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted
gatewayFilterFactories:
[[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@59918c8f},
order = -2147483648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@4bc9ca97},
order = -2147482648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@2450256f},
order = -1],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@24197b13}, order = 0],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@2776fd8f},
order = 0], [[RewritePath /portal(?<segment>/?.*) = '${segment}'],
order = 1], [[DedupeResponseHeader Authorization Cookie =
RETAIN_UNIQUE], order = 2],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@2b7facc7},
order = 10000],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayNoLoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$NoLoadBalancerClientFilter@1c62c3fd},
order = 10100],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@71b97eeb},
order = 2147483646],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@2c60ce47},
order = 2147483647],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@1c74d19},
order = 2147483647]] 2020-05-28 05:32:15.651 DEBUG 8492 ---
[tor-http-nio-10] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route
matched: business-object-service 2020-05-28 05:32:15.651 DEBUG 8492
--- [tor-http-nio-10] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET
http://localhost:3000/portal/api/business-object/reports/status-info-alb]
to Route{id='business-object-service', uri=http://localhost:9400,
order=0, predicate=Paths: [/portal/api/business-object/**], match
trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath
/portal(?<segment>/?.*) = '${segment}'], order = 1],
[[DedupeResponseHeader Authorization Cookie = RETAIN_UNIQUE], order =
2]], metadata={}} 2020-05-28 05:32:15.651 DEBUG 8492 ---
[tor-http-nio-10] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   :
[e36f913a-23] Mapped to
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@343c0132
2020-05-28 05:32:15.651 DEBUG 8492 --- [tor-http-nio-10]
o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted
gatewayFilterFactories:
[[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@59918c8f},
order = -2147483648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@4bc9ca97},
order = -2147482648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@2450256f},
order = -1],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@24197b13}, order = 0],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@2776fd8f},
order = 0], [[RewritePath /portal(?<segment>/?.*) = '${segment}'],
order = 1], [[DedupeResponseHeader Authorization Cookie =
RETAIN_UNIQUE], order = 2],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@2b7facc7},
order = 10000],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayNoLoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$NoLoadBalancerClientFilter@1c62c3fd},
order = 10100],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@71b97eeb},
order = 2147483646],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@2c60ce47},
order = 2147483647],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@1c74d19},
order = 2147483647]] 2020-05-28 05:32:15.703 DEBUG 8492 ---
[tor-http-nio-11] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route
matched: business-object-service 2020-05-28 05:32:15.703 DEBUG 8492
--- [tor-http-nio-11] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET
http://localhost:3000/portal/api/business-object/reports/status-info-alb]
to Route{id='business-object-service', uri=http://localhost:9400,
order=0, predicate=Paths: [/portal/api/business-object/**], match
trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath
/portal(?<segment>/?.*) = '${segment}'], order = 1],
[[DedupeResponseHeader Authorization Cookie = RETAIN_UNIQUE], order =
2]], metadata={}} 2020-05-28 05:32:15.703 DEBUG 8492 ---
[tor-http-nio-11] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   :
[fb10dd1f-24] Mapped to
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@343c0132
2020-05-28 05:32:15.703 DEBUG 8492 --- [tor-http-nio-11]
o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted
gatewayFilterFactories:
[[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@59918c8f},
order = -2147483648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@4bc9ca97},
order = -2147482648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@2450256f},
order = -1],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@24197b13}, order = 0],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@2776fd8f},
order = 0], [[RewritePath /portal(?<segment>/?.*) = '${segment}'],
order = 1], [[DedupeResponseHeader Authorization Cookie =
RETAIN_UNIQUE], order = 2],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@2b7facc7},
order = 10000],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayNoLoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$NoLoadBalancerClientFilter@1c62c3fd},
order = 10100],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@71b97eeb},
order = 2147483646],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@2c60ce47},
order = 2147483647],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@1c74d19},
order = 2147483647]] 2020-05-28 05:32:15.752 DEBUG 8492 ---
[tor-http-nio-12] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route
matched: business-object-service 2020-05-28 05:32:15.752 DEBUG 8492
--- [tor-http-nio-12] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET
http://localhost:3000/portal/api/business-object/reports/status-info-alb]
to Route{id='business-object-service', uri=http://localhost:9400,
order=0, predicate=Paths: [/portal/api/business-object/**], match
trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath
/portal(?<segment>/?.*) = '${segment}'], order = 1],
[[DedupeResponseHeader Authorization Cookie = RETAIN_UNIQUE], order =
2]], metadata={}} 2020-05-28 05:32:15.752 DEBUG 8492 ---
[tor-http-nio-12] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   :
[34e63694-25] Mapped to
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@343c0132
2020-05-28 05:32:15.752 DEBUG 8492 --- [tor-http-nio-12]
o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted
gatewayFilterFactories:
[[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@59918c8f},
order = -2147483648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@4bc9ca97},
order = -2147482648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@2450256f},
order = -1],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@24197b13}, order = 0],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@2776fd8f},
order = 0], [[RewritePath /portal(?<segment>/?.*) = '${segment}'],
order = 1], [[DedupeResponseHeader Authorization Cookie =
RETAIN_UNIQUE], order = 2],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@2b7facc7},
order = 10000],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayNoLoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$NoLoadBalancerClientFilter@1c62c3fd},
order = 10100],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@71b97eeb},
order = 2147483646],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@2c60ce47},
order = 2147483647],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@1c74d19},
order = 2147483647]] 2020-05-28 05:32:15.803 DEBUG 8492 ---
[ctor-http-nio-1] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route
matched: business-object-service 2020-05-28 05:32:15.803 DEBUG 8492
--- [ctor-http-nio-1] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET
http://localhost:3000/portal/api/business-object/reports/status-info-alb]
to Route{id='business-object-service', uri=http://localhost:9400,
order=0, predicate=Paths: [/portal/api/business-object/**], match
trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath
/portal(?<segment>/?.*) = '${segment}'], order = 1],
[[DedupeResponseHeader Authorization Cookie = RETAIN_UNIQUE], order =
2]], metadata={}} 2020-05-28 05:32:15.803 DEBUG 8492 ---
[ctor-http-nio-1] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   :
[ab9dbe90-26] Mapped to
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@343c0132
2020-05-28 05:32:15.804 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-1]
o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted
gatewayFilterFactories:
[[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@59918c8f},
order = -2147483648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@4bc9ca97},
order = -2147482648],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@2450256f},
order = -1],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@24197b13}, order = 0],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@2776fd8f},
order = 0], [[RewritePath /portal(?<segment>/?.*) = '${segment}'],
order = 1], [[DedupeResponseHeader Authorization Cookie =
RETAIN_UNIQUE], order = 2],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@2b7facc7},
order = 10000],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayNoLoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$NoLoadBalancerClientFilter@1c62c3fd},
order = 10100],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@71b97eeb},
order = 2147483646],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@2c60ce47},
order = 2147483647],
[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@1c74d19},
order = 2147483647]] 2020-05-28 05:32:15.855 ERROR 8492 ---
[ctor-http-nio-6] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler :
[d15d386e-19]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/portal/"

io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: HTTP header is larger
than 15000 bytes.   at
io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.newException(HttpObjectDecoder.java:915)
~[netty-codec-http-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]   Suppressed:
reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:  Error has
been observed at the following site(s):     |_ checkpoint ⇢
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter
[DefaultWebFilterChain]     |_ checkpoint ⇢
org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter
[DefaultWebFilterChain]     |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/portal/"
[ExceptionHandlingWebHandler] Stack trace:      at
io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.newException(HttpObjectDecoder.java:915)
~[netty-codec-http-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.increaseCount(HttpObjectDecoder.java:910)
~[netty-codec-http-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.process(HttpObjectDecoder.java:898)
~[netty-codec-http-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.forEachByteAsc0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1336)
~[netty-buffer-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.forEachByte(AbstractByteBuf.java:1316)
~[netty-buffer-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder$HeaderParser.parse(HttpObjectDecoder.java:872)
~[netty-codec-http-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.readHeaders(HttpObjectDecoder.java:572)
~[netty-codec-http-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.decode(HttpObjectDecoder.java:214)
~[netty-codec-http-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.decode(HttpClientCodec.java:202)
~[netty-codec-http-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
~[netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
~[netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
~[netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:271)
~[netty-handler-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]      at
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]        at
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]       at
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2020-05-28 05:32:17.680 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-6]
o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: frontend
2020-05-28 05:32:17.680 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-6]
o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET
http://localhost:8080/portal/sw.js] to Route{id='frontend',
uri=http://localhost:3000, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/**], match
trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[DedupeResponseHeader
Authorization Cookie = RETAIN_UNIQUE], order = 1]], metadata={}}
2020-05-28 05:32:17.680 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-6]
o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : [d15d386e-27] Mapped to
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@343c0132
2020-05-28 05:32:17.680 DEBUG 8492 --- [ctor-http-nio-6]
o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted
gatewayFilterFactories:
```

Comment: If you can replicate the problem without the frontend using curl, that would be helpful

Comment: @spencergibb is there a good way for me to output the headers being passed from the frontend to my gateway api request? As of now I can't determine if this is the frontend or the backend causing this issue. (I'm not a frontend expert and nuxt is doing server side rendering) I just need to be able to see what headers it's passing so I can attempt to replicate with curl.

Comment: you don't know what your frontend is sending? what version of gateway are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.3.0 for the gateway and as far as the frontend, it appears to be sending it serverside rather than front the client and I have very little experience with the frontend.

Comment: there's no version 2.3.0 of the gateway

Comment: Where u able to fix this issue? I am facing the same problem